# Modal "Please Wait" dialogue box with possible UI in the background process

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog, backgroundworker

I have a long running process we'll call ProcessA so I want to put a "Please Wait..." type dialogue box to discourage the user from trying to interact with the application and ensure they don't get "Not Responding" type info / errors (e.g. offering the opportunity to End Process)

My first thought is to set up a Background Worker to do the job and display a modal dialogue box in the foreground, and close it when ProcessA completes. However, the problem is that ProcessA throws up its own dialogue box at the end and then does some printing.

So if the user clicks anywhere on the application, ProcessA's dialogue box will disappear behind the application's window.

So how can I display the "Please Wait", but also prevent interaction with the main application while not having it show up as "Not Responding" while ProcessA is running?

ProcessA runs from a DLL and I don't have access to its code. (So I can't simply close the "Please Wait" when it's ready to show its own dialogue box)

Comment: You could try win API calls to monitor for the print dialog showing on ProcessA?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive sample.

```
class MyForm : Form {
    private void Form_Load() {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_=>{
            Form frmDialog = new Form();
            //Cross-thread InvokeRequired
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
                frmDialog.ShowDialog(this);
            }));

            // to do long-time work here

            // Cross-thread InvokeRequired
            this.Invoke(new Action(()=>{
                frmDialog.Dispose();
                // frmDialog.Close(); the Close method doesn't release the frmDialog, just make it invisible. (Memory leak !!!)
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Got errors but with slight modification, got it to build ( `this.Invoke(new Action(() => ...`). Unfortunately didn't solve the problem that the dialog box from the long time ProcessA would disappear behind the main application window if I click elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I just edit it with sublime on my MacBook. @colmde Could you please post your sample code?

Comment: Sorry I had deleted it after it didn't work the way I wanted, but I have edited your code to what I did (hope you don't mind)

Comment: @colmde It doesn't matter. Sorry I can't debug it with VS, cause I don't have Windows PC now, and I don't  also want to install Mono on my MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

My eventual resolution was just to use a Modeless "Please Wait", not perfect but hopefully will be acceptable for now...

```
_pleaseWaitForm.Show();
_pleaseWaitForm.Refresh();

DisableProcessWindowsGhosting();

ProcessA(); // Long running process

_pleaseWaitForm.Close(); // or maybe should it be Dispose()?
```

Since ProcessA ties up the UI it prevents user interaction anyway, and `DisableProcessWindowsGhosting()` prevents the "Not Responding" message or the user from closing the application if they get impatient.

A little bit sloppy so I'm still open to a more elegant answer...